# Typescript Does Not Scream When Trying to Construct an Object with Omitted Field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-intl

#### Background:

I'm trying to get typescript to scream when trying to pass an object that has a certain field, but can't make it work for this particular case.

An example code:

```
import * as React from "react";

// type ReactIntl.MessageValue = string | number | boolean | Date | null | undefined
export type IValues = {
    [key: string]: JSX.Element | ReactIntl.MessageValue;
} | undefined;

export interface INewValues extends Omit<IValues, 'date'> { }

const Foo = () => {
    const values: INewValues = { date: "25/10/2030" }; // No error

    console.log(values);

    return null;
}
```

Rendering the component will log the following into console:

```
>> {date: '25/10/2030'}
```

#### My question:

Is it possible to tell Typescript that assigning an object with a 'date' field into a variable of type "INewValues" is forbidden?
My goal is to create a type named "INewValues" that has everything "IValues" has, but without a 'date' field.

"IValues" is the type of `react-intl`'s `FormattedMessage` component's `values` prop. So basically what I'm trying to do is to forbid developers from passing a `values` object with a 'date' field.

**Note:**
When destructuring 'date' from values it does gives the following error as expected:
`"Property 'date' does not exist on type 'INewValues'."`

```
const values: INewValues = { date: "25/10/2030" }; // No error

const { date } = values; // Error

console.log(date);

>> 25/10/2030
```

Comment: Your `IValues` can have _any_ string key. You would need to constrain it with something like `key: 'date' | 'time' | 'space' | 'purple'` first...

Answer (score 2):

Disallowing keys doesn't fit the TypeScript model well, but if you really need it, you could declare a type `NeverInclude<T, K>` like this:

```
type NeverInclude<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T & Record<K, never>
```

It will trigger the desired error in `Foo`:

```
export interface INewValues extends NeverInclude<IValues, 'date'> {}

const Foo = () => {
    const values: INewValues = {
        elt: <div>'hi'</div>,
        date: "25/10/2030" // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    };

    console.log(values);

    return null;
}
```

It is a little quirky though, and won't fail on destructuring for example, as `const { date } = values` will just yield a `date` of type `never`. But if your main goal is to prevent people from passing objects with a `date` property, it might suite your use case.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQdWAHpLHDAJ5hZwCSAasgA2AVyzoAvHADedOPLgBtANZYOALjioYUYADsA5gF1NAKQDKADQB0AUSFYQWPfAA%20cAOTY8MXi6HWALLiqMgGWIKiWB70AL5w7iJ6ACZYBPpYyfR0nNxwAHJYAG5YUH64oqkAPAAqADRwANJwzDDOyegACsTcsByNagB8cFI1cABkmFi40MlVjQ16xaWDDMys8PptUAR4PLyFAO6RYuit7eiFJWV6FSLVAsKnDR7JyG0ew9KxDDN62nAAGIQCAjOAACgAlCMvnIFH8AUUnuJNAcsMdkZIZHCFAosEIYJoqslgEVBh4ABbADxVAD0JLJdRxuLgbzamjIACYAKy0gCMAAZaZyBQBmAVkOC02lwWwYDAAeQwmhqXB4Hm0ukMHjgwHQegg8DQqGABj0yAARg52KDcuqltcPNZmbFsriERAHNYhBADOCkVFUJC3QpKDARFA9HA9CIhEI4nQgA)

Note that the reason `Omit<IValues, 'date'>` yields an error on destructuring is not because of omitting `'date'` (it also happens when  any other key is omitted). It's because `IValues` can be `undefined`, and applying `Omit` to a value that can be undefined yields the type `{}` (because `keyof undefined` is `never`). This means all destructuring will fail and you can assign anything except `null` or `undefined` to `INewValues`, e.g.:

```
const test: INewValues = 42
const { nonDate } = values; // error
```

If you remove the `| undefined` from `IValues`, destructuring no longer errors:

```
export type IValuesRequired = {
    [key: string]: JSX.Element | ReactIntl.MessageDescriptor
};

export interface INewValuesRequired extends Omit<IValuesRequired, 'date'> {}

const FooRequired = () => {
    const values: INewValuesRequired = { date: "25/10/2030" };
    // different error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Element | MessageDescriptor'.

    const {date} = values // no error
}
```

(You do get an error on `date` now, but that's only because the value doesn't match)

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.2#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-WGsHyCGtKFbXb7aUJg0zBHnS43VHozHYvEQHNJkyk8lmXmWfn0uPMmParB63NGkyCgtYZxkLkAVhKAEYAAwlLljgDMY7I4voVPurWABAICuivUV0GcABVNadLZ4uu90ML4GhUMAPNxkAAjCJwIpPg9dcKRTcjNKexo+v0BqAumCWQqUbMxewlOApVBe5hTBbdlUGIA)

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to achieve both behaviors? (error on destructuring forbidden keys, and error on assigning an object with forbidden keys)

Comment: @Elyasaf755 I don't think so, unfortunately. The destructuring error with the `Omit` version also wasn't caused by omitting `'date'`. I've updated the answer a bit.

Comment: Maybe `Partial<Record<K, never>>` instead?

Comment: @jcalz You mean in the definition of `NeverInclude`? Won't that just block indexing with non-`date` keys, while still allowing indexing with `date`? https://tsplay.dev/wOJErW

Comment: I meant `T & Partial...` but yeah if it interacts badly then forget it 